# How to Scroll UITableView Automatically cell by cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image]

How to Scroll UITableView Automatically cell by cell.
**Well**, I think it's easy to achieve, and I did it so close

> This is my **SPEECH** function in ViewController below

```
var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
let speecher = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
func speechWord(word: String){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.speecher.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
        self.myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: word)
        self.myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
        self.myUtterance.rate = 0.5
        self.speecher.speak(self.myUtterance)
    }
}
```

> This is my **AutoSpeech** function in ViewController below

```
func startAutoSpeechList(row: Int){
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
    print(indexPath)
    myTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top) //Select
    myTableView.scrollToNearestSelectedRow(at: .top, animated: true) //Scroll
    let cell = tableView(myTableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! WordTableViewCell
    self.speechWord(word: cell.spell.text!) //Speech
}
```

> (**Method 1**) This is The Button I use to activate The AutoSpeech function

```
var row = 0
@IBAction func myAutoButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.startAutoSpeechList(row: row)
    row += 1
}
```

**Method 1, Look at The Image I uploaded** When I click AutoButton the first time, it jumps to Screen A.  And I click AutoSpeech Button again, it to Screen B.   Then I click AutoButton the third time, it jumps to Screen C.

> (**Method 2**) This is The Button I use to activate The AutoSpeech function

```
@IBAction func myAutoButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    for myRow in 0..<3{
        self.startAutoSpeechList(row: myRow)
    }
}
```

**Method 2,** When I click AutoSpeech Button, it jumps to Screen C **immediately** without staying Screen A,B for any time. Can you explain why it immediately escape Scree A, B?

> Is there **Method 3** to help me achieve that **When I click
>   AutoSpeech Button, it will jump to Screen A and pronounce the word
>   "cat", then jump to B after finishing the pronunciation and pronounce 
>   "dog", then jump to
>   C, and so on...**.  Who can help me to achieve Method 3? 
>   Swift 4 will be better for me.

Comment: Method 2 looks like it does exactly what you want, it just does it in milliseconds. You either need a timer to control the timing between rows or you need to know when each one finishes playing the speech so you can then move onto the next

Comment: The problem with Method 2 is that  **it jumps to Screen C immediately without staying Screen A, B**, how can I fix

Comment: I know, thats what I said in my comment? fix also suggested in comment above

Comment: Any method to observe whether it has finished playing the speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method 2 code is what you need, **but** it runs continuously and completes in milliseconds.

The best option available would be to use the [AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate) methods to monitor for did finish speaking.

In your case you can use

```
func speechSynthesizer(AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish: AVSpeechUtterance)
```

to be notified when the currently playing speech ends playing. Once this is called you could call a function like speakNextRow or something to move to the next in the list.

Roughly, This is the kind of thing you should be looking at doing. (not tested in xcode, use as a guide on how to do what you need).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

    var currentSelectedRow: Int?
    var isAutoPlaying = false

    var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
    let speecher = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.speecher.delegate = self
    }

    func speechWord(word: String){

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.speecher.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
            self.myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: word)
            self.myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
            self.myUtterance.rate = 0.5
            self.speecher.speak(self.myUtterance)
        }
    }

    func startAutoPlay() {
        isAutoPlaying = true
        currentSelectedRow = 0
        scrollToAndSpeak(at: currentSelectedRow)
    }

    func scrollToAndSpeak(at index: Int) {
        // make sure to check not going out of bounds!!
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        myTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top) //Select
        myTableView.scrollToNearestSelectedRow(at: .top, animated: true) //Scroll
        let cell = tableView(myTableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! WordTableViewCell
        self.speechWord(word: cell.spell.text!) //Speech
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish: AVSpeechUtterance) {
         if isAutoPlaying {
              // make sure to check not going out of bounds!!
              currentSelectedRow = (currentSelectedRow ?? 0) + 1
              scrollToAndSpeak(at: currentSelectedRow)
         }
    }
}
```

So when you select auto play, turn the flag isAutoPlaying to true and start playing the first one. Once this finishes the delegate will be notified and we increase the index and start playing the next one and so on until either the user cancels it or we run out of cells.

Comment: I've tested your answer, and it works for me. Thanks for your help. I think the function speechSynthesizer is necessary for observing whether it has finished the speech.